# How to use monadtrans?

Tags: haskell

I have following type:

```
newtype StateT' s m a =
  StateT' { runStateT' :: s -> m (a,s) }
```

and I implement the MonadTrans instance:

```
instance MonadTrans (StateT' s) where
  lift ma = StateT' $ \s -> do
    a <- ma
    return (a, s)
```

My questions are:

- Which type the statement `return (a, s)` is going to return? A tuple
  or the tuple wrapped in a monad?
- How to use the `lift` function and force to have to `StateT'` type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Which type the statement `return (a, s)` is going to return? A tuple or the tuple wrapped in a monad?

A tuple wrapped in a monad. `return (a, s) :: m (a, s)` which is good since `runStateT' :: s -> m (a, s)`

> How to use the lift function and force to have to `StateT'` type?

You probably don't need this. If you use `lift` where there's a type signature it should just work.

You can make a version of lift with a type signature that introduces the fact that you're lifting into `StateT' s`, but it won't help much since type inference will still need to infer `s`.

```
liftStateT' :: Monad m => m a -> StateT' s m a
liftStateT' = lift
```